# Cyclotomic integers with complex norm $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R=\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$. What are the elements in this ring with complex norm $1$? Are only $\zeta_n^i$ all such elements? What if $n$ is odd prime?

Comment: Try taking the norm of an element $a + b \zeta_n^k$ and impose it's equal to 1...

Comment: Obviously |a+bζ^k_n|>1 for all a,b except a=b=0.

Comment: Maybe you mean "unless $|a|+|b|=1$"...

Comment: complex norm 1 is equivalent to be a unit in $R$.

Comment: It is obviosly, that $(\zeta_n^i-1)/(\zeta-1)$ is unit in $R$, if ${\rm gcd}(i,n)=1$. But it is also obvious, that $\left|\zeta_n^i-1\right| \neq \left|\zeta_n-1\right|$ in general case.